# Logstash pipeline optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

We have the netscaler appliance syslogs sent to our ELK stack and the same is parsed using a custom pipeline created from our end. Though we are able to achieve what is intended with the pipeline configuration, we are noticing performance issues at our ingest nodes followed by queuing up of data in logstash which inturn is causing issues in the overall performance of our ELK Stack. The moment we add this pipeline configuration to our stack, the load goes high in ingest nodes. For which we have stopped the netscaler logs to be loaded into the system for now.

Can anyone please analyze this pipeline configuration and provide us with inputs on how we can improve with this without affecting the ELK performance.

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
"pipeline": {
    "description" : "Netscalaer logs",
    "processors" :[
  {
    "json": {
      "field": "message",
      "add_to_root": false,
      "target_field": "qrapp"
    }
  },
   {
    "grok": {
      "field": "qrapp.message",
      "patterns": [
        
        "%{DATA:qrapp.eventid} %{DATA:qrapp.event.timestamp} %{DATA:qrapp.event.timezone} %{DATA:qrapp.hostname} : %{CISCO_REASON:qrapp.msg1} : Context %{DATA:qrapp.context_user}@%{IP:qrapp.context_ip} - %{GREEDYDATA:qrapp.msg2}",
        "%{DATA:qrapp.eventid} %{DATA:qrapp.event.timestamp} %{DATA:qrapp.event.timezone} %{DATA:qrapp.hostname} : %{CISCO_REASON:qrapp.msg1} :%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:qrapp.msg2}",
        "%{DATA:qrapp.eventid} %{DATA:qrapp.event.timestamp} %{DATA:qrapp.event.timezone} %{DATA:qrapp.hostname} : %{GREEDYDATA:qrapp.msg}",
        "%{GREEDYDATA:qrapp.msg}"
      ],
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
   {
    "kv": {
      "field": "qrapp.msg2",
      "field_split": " - ",
      "value_split": " ",
      "target_field": "qrapp",
      "ignore_missing": true,
      "ignore_failure": true
    }
  },
  {
    "gsub": {
      "field": "qrapp.eventid",
      "pattern": "[\\<\\>]",
      "replacement": "",
      "ignore_missing": true,
      "ignore_failure": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Total_bytes_recv",
      "target_field": "qrapp.total_bytes_recv",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Total_bytes_send",
      "target_field": "qrapp.total_bytes_send",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Destination",
      "target_field": "qrapp.destination",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Nat_ip",
      "target_field": "qrapp.nat_ip",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.User",
      "target_field": "qrapp.user",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Vserver",
      "target_field": "qrapp.vserver",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Access",
      "target_field": "qrapp.access",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Source",
      "target_field": "qrapp.source",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Client_ip",
      "target_field": "qrapp.client_ip",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Compression_ratio_send",
      "target_field": "qrapp.compression_ratio_send",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Total_compressedbytes_send",
      "target_field": "qrapp.total_compressedbytes_send",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.End_time",
      "target_field": "qrapp.end_time",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Start_time",
      "target_field": "qrapp.start_time",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Duration",
      "target_field": "qrapp.duration",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Total_compressedbytes_recv",
      "target_field": "qrapp.total_compressedbytes_recv",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "field": "qrapp.Compression_ratio_recv",
      "target_field": "qrapp.compression_ratio_recv",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "date": {
      "formats": [
        "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        "dd-MMM-yy_HH.mm.ss.SSS",
        "yyyy-MM-d_HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS",
        "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss,SSS"
      ],
      "ignore_failure": true,
      "field": "qrapp.timestamp",
      "target_field": "@timestamp",
      "timezone": "Asia/Qatar"
    }
  },
  {
    "remove": {
      "field": ["qrapp.message", "message", "qrapp.msg2", "qrapp.context_ip", "qrapp.context_user"],
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  }
]
},
    "docs": [
     {
       "_source": {
         "message": """{"@version":"1","tags":["_grokparsefailure_sysloginput"],"message":"<134> 11/07/2022:08:02:00 GMT ************* 0-PPE-0 : default SSLVPN ICAEND_CONNSTAT 1314466465 0 :  Source *********:*** - Destination *********:*** - customername  - username:domainname *****@******: - startTime \"11/07/2022:07:57:46 GMT\" - endTime \"11/07/2022:08:02:00 GMT\" - Duration 00:04:14  - Total_bytes_send 73134 - Total_bytes_recv 44465 - Total_compressedbytes_send 0 - Total_compressedbytes_recv 0 - Compression_ratio_send 0.00% - Compression_ratio_recv 0.00% - connectionId 47345284 - Total_bytes_wire_send 4710555505001451848 - Total_bytes_wire_recv 5931570851812355409\n","severity_label":"Emergency","@timestamp":"2022-11-07T08:00:07.384Z","host":"********","facility_label":"kernel","severity":0,"priority":0,"facility":0}"""
         }
     }
   ]
}
```

Inputs are taken as below in logstash config:

```
input {
  
#Section for Netscaler

  syslog {
    port => ****
    id => "check-syslog"
   }
}

# output section
output {

#Section for Netscaler
  if [host] == '********'
  {
    file 
    {
     path => "*************.log"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grok is matching against an array of patterns, which suggests that most events will *not* match one or more of those patterns. Not matching a pattern can be very expensive, but there are things you can do to reduce the cost of not matching. [This](https://www.elastic.co/blog/do-you-grok-grok) blog post from Elastic provides background.

First, anchor your patterns if you can. If `%{DATA:qrapp.eventid}` always occurs at the start of the qrapp.message field, then change that to `^%{DATA:qrapp.eventid}`. Second, DATA, and especially GREEDYDATA, are expensive when they do not match. If your message field is space delimited it will be far cheaper to use NOTSPACE than DATA.